# How to mask fields in protobuff generated class from toString()

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm using protobuf version 2.6.1 and I have this message configured in my .proto file -

```
message Login {
    optional string host = 1;
    optional uint32 port = 2;
    optional string user = 3;
    optional string password = 4;
}
```

How can I mask user and password fields from being printed to log or in toString()?

Answer (score -3):

One way you can achieve this is using 'FieldMasks' in Proto 3.0 version

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/FieldMaskUtil.html

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/FieldMask

Elaborating,

1. Define you fieldMask as this:

> Login.user
>      , Login.password

2. Create a new Message with user and password set to null
3. Merge your source message and the above new message for printing. Use this method in FieldMaskUtil

> merge(FieldMask mask, Message source, Message.Builder destination)

Comment: i believe answer is misleading. The FieldMask does the reverse. It only prints what you specify in FieldMask. Here's the similar question asked by me ( i didnt read the FieldMask javadoc :-) also ) and expected it to mask : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355892/how-to-mask-certain-fields-in-protobuf

Comment: Why this answer is checked? Question is about protobuf 2, answer about protobuf 3.